# How to return string value through a sql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a query which **retuns a string** value as the output. But shows an error in the return. I dont know how to fix it. Here i have added my query.

```
public string detailsRemarksGet(string ddlValue)
{

     string strQuery = @"select r.remarks
                        from [A_MASTER] m, [A_REMARKS] r
                        where m.A_REF_NO=r.A_REF_NO 
                        and r.A_REF_NO='"+ ddlValue +"' and DEPT='POS' ";
     return SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(strConnStringAppeal, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
}
```

**Here is mky code of .cs**

```
public string detailsRemarks(string ddlValue)
{
   string remarks= db.detailsRemarksGet(ddlValue);
   return remarks;
}
```

**In the error list i get a message as follows**

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql query return `object` type, you need to cast that as `string`. So cast as `string` using `ToString()` method in return statement

```
return SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(strConnStringAppeal, CommandType.Text, strQuery).ToString();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the answer. I will accept it after few minutes

Comment: great, happy coding

Comment: You are not even going to mention the glaring SQL injection problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just **convert** your return type **to String**, because your method name **db.detailsRemarksGet** will return you an object and your **detailsRemarks** method return type is string.

```
public string detailsRemarks(string ddlValue)
{
    string remarks= Convert.ToString(db.detailsRemarksGet(ddlValue));
    return remarks;
}
```